# How to insert vertical material in a paragraph

Tags: formatting, line-breaking, paragraphs, vertical

What is the proper way to insert some vertical material inside a paragraph? Like what `quote` or display math do.

I want to have a `parbox` or a `minipage` inserted at a given point of my paragraph vertically, and then the paragraph be resumed (without indentation, in particular). I can do it by hard breaking the line with `\\`, but this does not feel like the right way, and this is not how displayed equations or `quote` environment behave.

Comment: use `quote` or `center` or `quotation`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, `quote` and `quotation` add an (unwanted) margin. `center` is OK for full-width boxes, but otherwise I would like to have the material left-justified, like in normal vertical mode.

Comment: `flushleft` is same as center but not centered, but all of those are simple one  line definitions wrapping `list` specifying the vertical space and alignment so if you don't want exactlly that just copy the definition and adjust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the definition of the `center` environment (`texdef -t latex center`) then you see it is defined as follows:

```
\begin{trivlist}\centering\item\relax
[body]
\end{trivlist}
```

So you can take that definition and remove the `\centering`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is the first line of a paragraph that has intentation. The goal is to have vertical material within the paragraph that is not indented, not centered, and does not indent the following line.
\begin{center}
The center environment does this but is centered
\end{center}
Some more text, not indented
\begin{trivlist}\item\relax
A trivlist is not centered and meets all three criteria
\end{trivlist}
End of the text, also not indented
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]